# Whats the equivalent of MySQL Set datatype in Oracle?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, oracle12c

In MySQL, we can use Set datatype to select multiple values for each column of any specific row as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `staff` ( `StaffID` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                  `Availability` set('Mon','Tue','Wed','Thur','Fri','SatAM','SatPM','Sun') DEFAULT NULL, 
                  PRIMARY KEY (`StaffID`))
```

Then I can do,

```
INSERT INTO `staff` (`Availability`) VALUES ('Tue,Wed,SatPM')
```

I tried to find everywhere but couldn't find any suitable datatype to store multiple selected options as above in Oracle. The Oracle documentation seems to show having no alternative for the MySQL set but I can't believe they don't have it! So could anyone help me out in clarifying this?

[Oracle Documentation reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uy8Pe.png) [Original link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12155/oracle_mysql_compared.htm#i1027526)

Comment: Just because mysql has a feature, doesn't mean it's a good idea/something an rdbms should have. You could do this with strings, xml, json or break what is effectively a many:many relationship up into a set of tables that associates "staff" with an "availableday" table via a "staff_availableday" table. Only the latter is really correct in a well normalized database

Comment: I think you'll need to design a different table structure in Oracle.

Comment: Besides to add to @CaiusJard 's comment..  changing MySQL's SET  datatype options would most iikely require a complete tabe rebuild and or table lock if InnoDB's online DDL could not be used.

Comment: What you are describing sounds vaguely similar to the `nested table` data type in Oracle SQL. There are some differences though. First, there is no generic nested table type in Oracle SQL; you must first `CREATE TYPE` to name a specific nested table data type, then you can use that in your `CREATE TABLE` statement, and you can use a constructor to `INSERT` values. Then, nested tables are multi-sets (they allow duplicates) - not sure if the `set` data type does (probably not).

Comment: Finally, it seems that `set` constrains the values just to those declared in `CREATE TABLE`; not sure if something equivalent exists in Oracle, but if it does, it's most likely done through constraints.

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL, the set data type is a named bit-mapped data type.  Oracle does not have one, though you could emulate it if you really wanted to by using a constrained integer data type:

```
CREATE TABLE staff (
    staffid INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( START WITH 1 NOCACHE ORDER ) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  , availability INTEGER CHECK ( availability BETWEEN 0 AND 256 )
);
```

You'll have to remember or build a function to map between the bitmap values and days.

Another option is to use a lookup table:

```
create table availability as
with t1(id, mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, satam, satpm, sun) as (
select 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 from dual
union all
select id+1
     , sign(bitand(id+1,1))
     , sign(bitand(id+1,2))
     , sign(bitand(id+1,4))
     , sign(bitand(id+1,8))
     , sign(bitand(id+1,16))
     , sign(bitand(id+1,32))
     , sign(bitand(id+1,64))
     , sign(bitand(id+1,128))
  from t1 where id+1 <256
)
select * from t1;

alter table availability add primary key (id);

CREATE TABLE staff (
    staffid INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY ( START WITH 1 NOCACHE ORDER ) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  , availability INTEGER 
  , CONSTRAINT staff_avail_fk FOREIGN KEY ( availability ) REFERENCES availability ( id ) 
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sentinel's answer (which I upvoted) addresses the question as literally asked.

However, I'm going to take a step back and, addressing the question as "how do I represent this type of data in Oracle", advise that a better solution to that problem is to *not* emulate the Set datatype.

The Set datatype is arguably a violation of first normal form.  That isn't necessarily a moral judgement about its usage; such solutions make certain queries easier and/or more efficient, and others more difficult and/or less efficient.  But the normal forms are built around many, many years of experience with RDBMS.  For a wide range of applications, adhering to the first three normal forms is a good way to avoid problems on balance.

A normalized solution which can be implemented in Oracle (without jumping through hoops to emulate bit-field enumerations) might include a `Staff` table with an ID, an `AvailabilityCode` table with a row for each individual value in the set, and `StaffAvailability`, a cross-reference between the two with a row for each AvailabilityCode value you want to associate with a Staff id.